# Mysql - add current timestamp field without affecting the existing records

Tags: mysql, timestamp

Suppose there there is a mysql table named users having 100 entries in it.

If I added a created_on field like

alter table users add created_on TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;

Those 100 records created_on will be filled with current timestamp.

I want it to only for new insertions. and want to keep null for existing records.

Is this possible?

Comment: Run this after creating the column? `UPDATE users SET created_at = NULL`

Answer (score 2):

Add it and then set the default:

```
alter table users add created_on timestamp null;
alter table users change created_on created_on timestamp null default current_timestamp;
```

That sets it to null for all existing records, and then provides the default for new records.